# Creating a decimal number with no decimal separator

Tags: java, decimalformat

I am trying to receive an int, which is always a number with 2 decimals.
Ex:

- 1000 is 10,00 (my decimal separator is comma).
- 100 is 1,00
- 0 is 0,00
- 100099 is 1.000,99

So I'm trying to avoid using String operators and use the DecimalFormat with the pattern 0,00 and German locale.

But when I get 10004, the output that I obtain is 1.00.04

This is my code:

```
public static String formatDecimal(double number) {
    //String pattern  = "#,00";
    String pattern  = "0,00";
    DecimalFormat fN = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.GERMAN);
    fN.applyPattern(pattern); 

    return fN.format(number)
}
```

Comment: why don't you try `(float) variable/ 100` ?

Comment: I don't think you can squeeze in a decimal separator symbol before the last two characters like that. I wouldn't use floating point arithmetic either due to rounding issues. Use BigDecimal or `intPart = number/100;` and `fracPart = number % 100` and print them as two integers separated with a decimal point.

Comment: Yes, I tried that already...the point is I need the decimal and thousand separator...and your advice have a different behavior when the data is one digit or more (because I recibe directly as a NUMBER from database...when is 0 I must show 0,00 (1 is 1,00 - 99 is 0,99 - 123 is 1,23) and figures thousands like 123456 is 1.234,56...

Comment: Try something like `String.format("%,d,%02d", i / 100, i % 100)`. (edit: hmm.. actually, I don't think you can set the thousand separator to `.` using `String.format` so you'd probably have to resort to `DecimalFormat` for the first part of the number.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you use your own pattern? Java default implementation has pretty good patterns in most of locales. At least by looking [Oracle's docs](http://www.oracle.com/us/technologies/java/locale-140624.html) it looks that it should do what you need to:

```
Locale                  Formatted Numbers
German (Germany)        123.456,789
German (Switzerland)    123'456.789
English (United States) 123,456.789
```

So what you have to do ( besides dividing a number by 100 ) is set minimum fraction digits to "2":

```
public static String formatDecimal(double number) {
    NumberFormat german = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.GERMAN);
    german.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
    return german.format(number / 100);
}
```

Edited: prints numbers as expected:

```
0,00
0,01
0,02
0,09
0,10
0,11
0,99
1,00
1,01
9,99
10,00
10,01
99,99
100,00
100,01
999,99
1.000,00
1.000,01
9.999,99
10.000,00
10.000,01
99.999,99
100.000,00
100.000,01
999.999,99
1.000.000,00
1.000.000,01
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
public static String formatDecimal(double number) {
    DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.GERMANY);
    dfs.setGroupingSeparator('.');
    return new DecimalFormat("0,00", dfs).format(number / 100);
}

formatDecimal(1000);   // 10,00
formatDecimal(100);    // 1,00
formatDecimal(0);      // 0,00
formatDecimal(100099); // 1.000,99
```

Comment: 100099 is 1.000,99 .. This is what he asks for ? What does that mean ?

Comment: @PritamBanerjee, OP is presumably working with currency and represents prices in cents using integers. (S)he then want's to display them as full Euros (or dollars or whatever).

Comment: But a decimal after 1 and then a comma. How can a currency be like that ? 1.00,34 doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I don't follow you. OP didn't say he wanted "1.00,34".

Comment: Thanks Jean, this is almost the solution..but I have a difference I don't know the thousand separator doesn't appear...            
System.out.println(formatDecimal(0));   0,00
System.out.println(formatDecimal(4));   0,04
System.out.println(formatDecimal(12));   0,12
System.out.println(formatDecimal(123));   1,23
System.out.println(formatDecimal(1234));  12,34
System.out.println(formatDecimal(12345));  123,45
System.out.println(formatDecimal(123456));  1234,56